# ngModel is not working, FillTeachersChangesComponent.html:23 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: html, angular

i'm developing a table in angular6, ts trying to do an editable table, 
and need to use [(ngModel)] to know what does the user entered, and then export it to an excel sheet...

the  problem is that he writes me Cannot read property '0' of undefined, 
although I defined the Array... 
and also doesn't shows the second *ngfor as i shown on attached picture
[image: here you can see]
here is my html:
........................
...
          
            
              
              
              
              
              
                {{days[i+1]}}

```
        <tr *ngFor=" let item of days;index as i">
          <td>
            <span>שם המורה</span><br />
            <input list="teachers" placeholder="הכנס שם" [(ngModel)]="subTeacherChanges.subbedTeacher[i]" name="a" />
          </td>

          <datalist id="teachers">
            <option *ngFor=" let item of teachersList; index as w " value="{{teachersList[w].name}}">
          </datalist>

          <td>
            <span>מילאה מקום המורה </span> <br />
            <input list="subTeachers" placeholder="הכנס שם" [(ngModel)]="subTeacherChanges.subTeacherName[i]"
              name="aa" />
          </td>

          <datalist id="subTeachers">
            <option *ngFor=" let item of subTeachersList; index as q" value="{{subTeachersList[q].name}}">
          </datalist>
          <td>
            <button> לחצי לצפיה בסך כל השעות שדווחו על המורה </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <span>א-ו</span><br />
            <span>ו-ח</span>
          </td>

          <small>
            <td style="width:5px" *ngFor=" let item of days;index as h">
              <input style="width: 15px" [(ngModel)]="subTeacherChanges.hoursSubbed1[i][h]" name="aaa" />
              <input style="width: 15px" [(ngModel)]="subTeacherChanges.hoursSubbed2[i][h]" name="aaaa" />
            </td>
          </small>

        </tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the ts:

```
   ...
export class FillTeachersChangesComponent implements OnInit {

  papa: Papa;
  days: number[] = [];
  days1: number[] = [];


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

  }


  //days:number=new Array[31];
  //teachersList:TeacherModel[]=[];
  teacherChanges: TeacherChangesModel[] = [];
  subTeacherChanges: SubTeachersChangesModel[] = [];


  teachersList: Array<TeacherModel> = [
    { id: 0, id1: '0', name: 'הכנס שם', lastName: 'הכנס משפחה', nikName: 'הכנס כינוי', Sunday: 0, Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 0, Friday: 0, Sunday1: 0, Monday1: 0, Tuesday1: 0, Wednesday1: 0, Thursday1: 0, Friday1: 0 },
    { id: 1, id1: '0', name: 'הכנס שם', lastName: 'הכנס משפחה', nikName: 'הכנס כינוי', Sunday: 0, Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 0, Friday: 0, Sunday1: 0, Monday1: 0, Tuesday1: 0, Wednesday1: 0, Thursday1: 0, Friday1: 0 },
    { id: 2, id1: '0 ', name: 'הכנס שם', lastName: 'הכנס משפחה', nikName: 'הכנס כינוי', Sunday: 0, Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 0, Friday: 0, Sunday1: 0, Monday1: 0, Tuesday1: 0, Wednesday1: 0, Thursday1: 0, Friday1: 0 },
    { id: 3, id1: '0', name: 'הכנס שם', lastName: 'הכנס משפחה', nikName: 'הכנס כינוי', Sunday: 0, Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 0, Friday: 0, Sunday1: 0, Monday1: 0, Tuesday1: 0, Wednesday1: 0, Thursday1: 0, Friday1: 0 },
    { id: 4, id1: '0', name: 'הכנס שם', lastName: 'הכנס משפחה', nikName: 'הכנס כינוי', Sunday: 0, Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 0, Friday: 0, Sunday1: 0, Monday1: 0, Tuesday1: 0, Wednesday1: 0, Thursday1: 0, Friday1: 0 },
    { id: 5, id1: '0', name: 'הכנס שם', lastName: 'הכנס משפחה', nikName: 'הכנס כינוי', Sunday: 0, Monday: 0, Tuesday: 0, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 0, Friday: 0, Sunday1: 0, Monday1: 0, Tuesday1: 0, Wednesday1: 0, Thursday1: 0, Friday1: 0 },
  ];

....

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let index = 0; index < 32; index++) {
      this.days.push(index);
      this.days1.push(index);

    }
      for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
        this.subTeacherChanges.push(new SubTeachersChangesModel);
        this.teacherChanges.push(new TeacherChangesModel);

      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: You checked the input line with `[(ngModel)]="subTeacherChanges.subTeacherName[i]"` ? I think you need to access with `[(ngModel)]="subTeacherChanges[i].subTeacherName`

Comment: put `*ngIf` in input to check `[(ngModel)] = "subTeacherChanges[i].subTeacherName` exists or not. so first write if condition like this.. `*ngIf="subTeacherChanges[i].subTeacherName"`